# html code as a value for textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea, cdata

I am working on simple code editor and I have this simple HTML page:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>Hello world !</p>
</div>
```

I need to create simple form that would allow me to edit this page and save changes, this is my code:

```
<?php
  $text = file_get_contents("test.html");
?>
<form method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <textarea name="text"  value="<?php echo $text;  ?>" >
        </textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work right and it does not parse all html code as text , this is real value of textarea after runing script

```
<h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Hello world !</p>
</div>" >
```

It looks like it parsed div with class declaration as valid html code, not as text.

Probably caused by `"`.

I also try this but result was exactly same:

```
<textarea name="text"  value="<?php echo "<![CDATA[".$text."]]>";  ?>" >
```

Can anyone help me to get all content of html page as value of textarea ?

Comment: Try this and similar functions http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: No value in textarea. Use this:         `<textarea name="text" >
<?php echo $text;  ?>
        </textarea>`

Comment: @RelicSet it works perfect for me when passing the content between <textarea> tags. It's breaking the value parameter because it's inside double quotes and they are broken by the div's double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add data to the text area you need to echo between `<textarea>` tags, not as a value. ([textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) documentation).

```
<textarea name="text"><?php echo $text;?></textarea>
```

Comment: Well, that works until the user schemingly decides to add a "</textarea>" to the $text, and suddenly he's writing html directly in the document.

Comment: To be fair the question didn't imply that it was user input and I think I would have complicated the answer if I sanitised the input

Comment: No sweat! ;-) I'm just considering unaware people coming across it and using it as a solution for user input, not considering sanitation. I actually had this code, knew it wasn't sanitary, and found this Q/A hoping it would show how to escape it. Anyhow, I just threw 'htmlspecialchars' around it, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the one of the following

```
<textarea name="text"><?php echo $text;  ?></textarea>

or 

<textarea name="text"><?php echo htmlentities($text)  ?></textarea>

or 

<textarea name="text"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text)  ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

It simple this

```
<textarea name="text" rows="10" cols="50"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
```

Here `cols` and `rows` are the attribute of `textarea`.you can't place you 
value in that place.you can place your value `<?PHP echo $text;?>` in between `<textarea></textarea>`

Answer (score -1):

You need to include your values between tags `<textarea></textarea>`:

```
<textarea name="text"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
```